# How to I get access NavigationService in a WIndows Phone app without going through a PhoneApplicationPage?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to I get access NavigationService in a Windows Phone app without going through a PhoneApplicationPage? My goal is to pass it to the application's primary view-model on startup, a technique that worked quite well for me in WPF and Silverlight.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can get it from the app's `PhoneApplicationFrame`. It will be accessible from anywhere in the app since every Windows Phone app has a Frame.

```
((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Navigate(...);
```

Comment: @Doug - Thanks! Glad to help whenever I can :)

Comment: @Nexus - You're welcome. Nice to see the answer's still useful :D

Answer (score 1):

Another place to get it is from the RootFrame field in the default implementation of Application:

```
    #region Phone application initialization

    // Avoid double-initialization
    private bool phoneApplicationInitialized = false;

    // Do not add any additional code to this method
    private void InitializePhoneApplication()
    {
        if (phoneApplicationInitialized)
            return;

        // Create the frame but don't set it as RootVisual yet; this allows the splash
        // screen to remain active until the application is ready to render.
        RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrame();
        RootFrame.Navigated += CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;

        // Handle navigation failures
        RootFrame.NavigationFailed += RootFrame_NavigationFailed;

        // Ensure we don't initialize again
        phoneApplicationInitialized = true;
    }

    // Do not add any additional code to this method
    private void CompleteInitializePhoneApplication(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Set the root visual to allow the application to render
        if (RootVisual != RootFrame)
            RootVisual = RootFrame;

        // Remove this handler since it is no longer needed
        RootFrame.Navigated -= CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;
    }


    #endregion
```