# Windows Phone navigation to other page

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm trying to navigate to another page. I'm using the MVVM pattern. So my button is binded to a command:

```
private ICommand inscriptionPage;

    public ICommand InscriptionPage
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.inscriptionPage == null)
                this.inscriptionPage = new MyCommand(() => callInscriptionFunction());

            return this.inscriptionPage;
        }
    }

    public void callInscriptionFunction()
    {
       PhoneApplicationPage nav = new PhoneApplicationPage();
        nav.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Views/Registration/Registration.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

I have this Exception at the last line:

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

I check on the web, tried different option, but this error is still there.

Edit: I tried to change the command to put it directly in the code behind. But I have a Debugger.break error.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Views/Registration/Registration.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8751806/815938) in your command; Also, pay attention to the **relative** Uri, the Uri path could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First, your Uri should begin with a slash, so change `new  Uri("Views/Registration/Registration.xaml", UriKind.Relative)` to `new Uri("/Views/Registration/Registration.xaml", UriKind.Relative)`. This should make your code behind work.

Second, creating a `PhoneApplicationPage` is a really strange and wrong idea. If you are not using a MVVM framework that provides navigation service, usu this

```
App.RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/Registration/Registration.xaml", UriKind.Relative))
```